# Make hlint run ever time ghc and ghci does?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, developer-tools, geany, hlint

How can you make HLint run evertime you compile or interpret a haskell module with ghc (or inside of ghci.)

Note: I am using geany on Ubuntu.

Comment: This kind of thing is generally done with tools like flymake, or inotifywatch (https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki), triggering off the file being saved rather than off running another tool. You should mention your OS and preferred editor, to help us tell you what you need. Editors that integrate ghc-mod usually have flymake+hlint enabled (see http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/)

Comment: I have hlint run through SublimeLinter-hlint with Sublime Text 3, I don't even have to have GHCi running to get immediate feedback.  I know this functionality exists in many other editors as well, but I haven't heard of having it run on a module you're importing in GHCi or when compiling with GHC.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/ocharles/hlint-source-plugin.